# rails 3, how to insert variables into an xml view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

one of our controller methods is invoked by a remote system, and it returns only xml.

in our foo controller we have

```
  def return_some_data
    @thename = "JOHN DOE" 
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml
      end
  end
```

in our views/foo/return_some_data.xml we have

```
<Response>
  <Name>#{@thename}</Name>  << that doesnt work
</Response>
```

I thought, like haml views, that #{@thename} would be substituted, but it's not.

How do I 'insert' variable data into this XML view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the file with an extension that makes it being processed by one of the engines. I imagine you could just rename the return_some_data.xml to return_some_data.xml.erb to have it processed by the standard engine. You will then have to use a slightly different syntax for you embedded code:

```
<Response>
  <Name><%= @thename%></Name> 
</Response>
```

Comment: I thought there WAS an XML engine though, and therefore some syntax where naming the file .xml and using some syntax would have the variable replaced?

Comment: @jpwynn...It is same like in the case of html..html.erb makes embedded ruby to be placed in html files..likewise xml.erb allows embedded ruby to be placed in xml files.

Answer (score 0):

To insert data into an XML document With Rails 3 and HAML, your view could look like the following.

return_some_data.xml.haml:

```
!!! XML
%document
  != @modelthing.to_xml(:skip_instruct => true)
  %some_var= @thename
  %another_var = @thetitle
```

Back with rails 2.3 this was just:

```
%document
  = @modelthing.to_xml
  %some_var= @thename
  %another_var = @thetile
```